# Command `source` doesn't work in Dockerfile

Tags: bash, docker, sh

I want build my images, here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

MAINTAINER 'hulei886@aliyun.com'

ENV PHANTOMJS_VERSION 2.1.1 
ENV PYTHON_VERSION 3.6.3

# install python3.6.3
RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y build-essential \
                       git \
                       curl \
                       libssl-dev \ 
                       zlib1g-dev \
                       libncurses5-dev \
                       libncursesw5-dev \
                       libreadline-dev \
                       libsqlite3-dev \

 && apt-get install -y libgdbm-dev \
                       libdb5.3-dev \
                       libbz2-dev \
                       libexpat1-dev \
                       liblzma-dev \ 
                       tk-dev \

 && cd ~ \

 && git clone https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv.git .pyenv \
 && echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> ~/.bashrc \
 && echo 'export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc \
 && echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc \
 && source ~/.bashrc \

 && curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yyuu/pyenv- installer/master/bin/pyenv-installer | bash \

 && pyenv install PYTHON_VERSION \

 && pyenv global PYTHON_VERSION \
 && cd .. \
 CMD [python]
```

but when i run "docker build . -t [mytag]"，
git clone command didn't clone anything,here is screenshot:
[image]

I need help to fix this problem,thanks！

Comment: pyenf folder exist? and why a dot before 'pyenf'?

Comment: It's difficult to tell what's actually failing as you're concatenating all your calls. Until you get this working, can you split them onto separate lines to see which specific line actually failing

Comment: `source` is a bash extension; your shell is not bash. See the POSIX spec for [the dot command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_18), which is the portable equivalent. And since `sh` *is not* bash, there shouldn't be a bash tag on this question; bash isn't involved in it anywhere.

Answer (score 5):

The error message is pretty clear:

```
/bin/sh: 1: source: not found
```

No problem with `git clone` but with `source` in a `/bin/sh` shell. You need to use the `.` (dot) command instead.

When writing a Dockerfile, it's better to test the commands in a container with `/bin/sh` shell.

In your case, after the `source` error, there are other errors:

- space in the curl URL
- env variable wrongly used: missing `$` prefix
- useless `cd ~`: only [`WORKDIR` instruction](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir) will change the current directory when running containers from the resulting image
- `CMD` instruction wrongly inserted in the `RUN` instruction

A fixed version would be:

```
[...]
  && git clone https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv.git .pyenv \
  && echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> ~/.bashrc \
  && echo 'export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc \
  && echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc \
  && . ~/.bashrc \

  && curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yyuu/pyenv-installer/master/bin/pyenv-installer | bash \

  && pyenv install $PYTHON_VERSION \
  && pyenv global $PYTHON_VERSION

WORKDIR /root
CMD [python]
```

Comment: This is correct, you will also need to replace the `bash` command after the `curl` with the ubuntu equivalent.

Comment: but when I run "docker run -it --rm ubuntu:16:04 /bin/sh",and run command in my dockerfile step by step,it was all right,no any problem

Answer (score 4):

You have to use source alternative in bash. You can do something like

> . somefile

instead of

> source somefile